# Determine event persistence

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

hope you are all safe and well. I Had an R problem that I think may be straight forward, but I cannot come up with a succinct code for it.
Lets say I have a column called "Bloom", that has 0 for when no bloom is detected, and then starts from 1 until there is no bloom and it restarts to 0. I want to create a new column that tells me how long the bloom persists.
Here I created an example dataframe that has as example of a bloom. First 4 days no bloom, then there is a bloom that lasts for 6 days, so the new column that I would want would produce a "6" to indicate that bloom lasted for 6 days.

```
bloom<- c(0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0)
persistence<- c(0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0)
bloom.df<- data.frame(bloom, persistence)
```

I was thinking that you would count the number of values >0 and populate the new column with however many there are and then restart once a 0 is detected, but not sure if that is the best solution doe that.
I appreciate any help and advice!

Answer (score 0):

Base R option with `rle` :

```
bloom.df$result <- with(rle(bloom.df$bloom != 0), rep(values * lengths, lengths))
bloom.df

#   bloom persistence result
#1      0           0      0
#2      0           0      0
#3      0           0      0
#4      0           0      0
#5      1           6      6
#6      2           6      6
#7      3           6      6
#8      4           6      6
#9      5           6      6
#10     6           6      6
#11     0           0      0
#12     0           0      0
#13     0           0      0
```

---

A `dplyr` option with the help of `data.table`s `rleid` function :

```
library(dplyr)

bloom.df %>% 
  add_count(grp = data.table::rleid(bloom == 0), name = 'result') %>%
  mutate(result = result * as.integer(bloom > 0)) %>%
  select(-grp)
```

For comparison purposes I have created a new column called `result`. You can obviously replace it with `persistence` if you wish.

Comment: I like the dplyr option, thank you so much, worked flawlessly!